# four-dimensional Levi-Civita

Tags: tensors, wolfram-physics

Consider we have these four vectors  $p^{\mu}$, $q^{\nu}$, $k^{\rho}$, and $k'^{\sigma}$.

How can we calculate
$$
\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} p^{\mu} q^{\nu} k^{\rho} k′^{\sigma}$$
in Mathematica, where $\epsilon$ is the 4D Levi-Civita tensor?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by the last expression. If you meant to sum over repeated indices (Einstein notation) perhaps something like this? `TensorContract[TensorProduct[LeviCivitaTensor[4],Array[p,4],Array[q,4],Array[k,4],Array[kp,4]],{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]`

Comment: As with your other questions, please show the *Mathematica* code that you've tried.